# How to add ServletForwardingController to GrailsDispatcherServlet in Grails 3?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, vaadin, grails3

I am trying to configure Grails 3.2 application to use Vaadin 8 alongside the dispatcher servlet. I added a compile dependency on "com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0.beta1", which pulls necessary spring machinery (e.g. SpringVaadinServlet etc.) and Vaadin dependency. Spring Vaadin add-on depends on ServletForwardingController configured to forward all Vaadin requests to Spring Vaadin servlet from DispatcherServlet. How should I configure that for GrailsDispatcherServlet? At best, this would be something that could be put into a plugin for reuse.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you might have a look at what Stephan Grundner did to integrate Vaadin 7 with Grails 3 : https://github.com/vaadin-for-grails/grails3-vaadin7-plugin

I'm currently using his plugin with Grails 3.1 and Vaadin 7.7.5 and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if Vaadin Spring Boot Starter is used (and it was in my case), Spring Boot autoconfiguration kicks in and configures both servlets (GrailsDispatcherServlet and SpringVaadinServlet) and whole Vaadin machinery without any problem. The real issue was that, even though I had my UI class annotated with @SpringUI, it wasn't picked up by auto-scanning and in effect it wasn't managed by the bean container. The easiest way to make it work was to add @ComponentScan annotation to Grails Application class. The other option would be to add a proper entry in application.yml:

```
grails:
profile: web
codegen:
    defaultPackage: example
spring:
    bean:
        packages:
            - example
```